# Merging Binary search tree

Tags: algorithm, merge, binary-search-tree

I'm looking for a efficient way of merging two BST, knowing that the elements in the first tree are all lower than those in the second one.
I saw some merging methods but without that feature, i think this should simplify the algorithm.

Any idea ?

Comment: Are the trees *balanced* Do they suppose to stay that way?

Comment: The trees are not balanced but should not be filiform

Comment: What is "filiform"? You mean you don't want/allow a simple placement of one tree into the other? You need to do *some* sort of balancing to fully merge them together, is that what you mean?

Comment: Sorry i'm french, i mean that I don't want to have a tree where every node has only one son. Like a stringy(?) tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the trees are not balanced, or the result shouldn't be balanced that's quite easy:

```
without loss of generality - let the first BST be smaller (in size) than the second.
1. Find the highest element in the first BST - this is done by following the right son while it is still available. Let the value be x, and the node be v
2. Remove this item (v) from the first tree
3. Create a new Root with value x, let this new root be r
4. set r.left = tree1.root, r.right = tree2.root
```

(*) If the first BST is bigger in size than the second, just repeat the process for finding `v` as the smallest node in the second tree.

(*) Complexity is `O(min{|T1|,|T2|})` worst case (finding highest element if the tree is very inbalanced), and `O(log(min{|T1|,|T2|}))` average case  - if the tree is relatively balanced.